Relation linking pairs of non-negative continuous or integer variables
I would like to ask about the constraints representing the following implications, where $x$ and $y$ are both either non-negative real or integer variables, and a, b are either non-negative continuous or integer constants:
$x\gt a \iff y\ge b$ and $x=0 \iff y=0$

Let $\bar{x}$ and $\bar{y}$ be constant upper bounds on $x$ and $y$, respectively.
Let $\epsilon$ be a small positive constant. Introduce binary variables $z_i$, and impose
\begin{align}
z_1 + z_2 + z_3 &= 1 \\
0 z_1 + \epsilon z_2 + (a+\epsilon) z_3 \le x &\le 0 z_1 + a z_2 + \bar{x} z_3 \\
0 z_1 + \epsilon z_2 + b z_3 \le y &\le 0 z_1 + (b-\epsilon) z_2 + \bar{y} z_3
\end{align}
The idea is that
\begin{align}
z_1 = 1 &\iff (x=0 \land y=0) \\
z_2 = 1 &\iff (0 < x \le a \land 0 < y < b) \\
z_3 = 1 &\iff (x > a \land y \ge b)
\end{align}

Thank you! If I were make subtle change by changing it to x>=a, may I ask what changes do I need to make?

In that case, replace each $a$ with $a-\epsilon$ in the second constraint.

Thank you again!

Upon closer inspection, it seems that Z_1 has no effect on the outcomes of both logical constraints, hence can just replace Z_1+Z_2+Z_3 =1 by Z_2+Z_3. In effect, can I confirm with you that it has same effect of incorporating  (x=0 and y=0) with (0<x<=a and 0<y<b), resulting in (0<=x<=a and 0=<y<b)? Thank you

You can think of $z_1$ as a slack variable for $z_1+z_2+z_3=1$, and you can replace that equality with the inequality $z_2+z_3\le 1$.

Thank you for the clarification, this clears up everything.
